# Alternative to Django Admin pages

Tags: database, django

I need to write a simple database editor and I like the customizable Admin pages of Django. I still wonder if there is an alternative that would allow me to define my models (or use something like SQLAlchemy) and show me a simple admin page where I could read, write, and create my records like Django.

Comment: I just discovered that I could use Django Admin like PhpMyAdmin, but in a more user-friendly way. I then wondered if there was an alternative because I always have multiple solutions available in the open-source world, and I found nothing like this.

Answer (score 3):

[web2py](http://web2py.com/) have this kind of functionality. If you want to work with SQLAlchemy there's [Camelot](http://www.python-camelot.com/) that give a Qt GUI and [Rum](http://python-rum.org/) for a web interface. I know that, at some times, [TurboGears](http://turbogears.org/) add an admin interface named [Catwalk](http://turbogears.org/1.0/docs/Catwalk.html), but I don't know the state of it currently.